# How to test if search result was found?

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap

I perform this search, where `$_` can be a DN for for group or an user.

```
my $m = $ldap->search(
  base => "$_", 
  scope => 'base',
  filter => '(objectClass=Person)',
  attrs => ['sAMAccountName'], 
  );

if (defined($m->entry->entries->get_value('sAMAccountName'))) {
  print $m->entry->entries->get_value('sAMAccountName') . "\n";
}
```

This problem this is, if `$_` is a group, then `sAMAccountName` doesn't exist, and the script fails. I am not even sure if this works for an user =(

Does anyone know how to only print the `sAMAccountName` if `$_` is a person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the search object's entries. If the attribute does not exist, it will be `undef` (of course), but not cause a failure because we do not attempt to dereference a method call from it.

```
foreach my $entry ($m->entries) {
    my ($uid, $sAMAccountName) = (
        $entry->get_value('uid'),
        $entry->get_value('sAMAccountName'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your filter is:

```
(objectClass=Person)
```

Then you will retrieve no entries when $_ is a group.

So instead of that horrible defined() call, check to see if `$m->entries()` is empty.

Example:

```
my $m = $ldap->search(
  base => "$_", 
  scope => 'base',
  filter => '(objectClass=Person)',
  attrs => ['sAMAccountName'], 
  );

my @entries = $m->entries();

if (@entries) {
  print $m->entry->entries->get_value('sAMAccountName') . "\n";
}
```